# iOS - set MAXIMUM touchCount

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm taking a UITapGestureRecognizer in order to turn a comic-book page. When I take the tap, I send:

```
    [comicScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(nextPageCGPoint) animated:YES];
```

-- in other words, on a tap event I animate the content offset of a scroll view, to show the next page in the scroll view.

The problem is, I want to NOT let another tap gesture affect the contentOffset unless the animation has finished. The problem is, in practice, I've found this very difficult -- I've tried setting an "isAnimating" Boolean to YES before setting the content offset, then setting it to NO with a callback; I've tried setting an animation:completion: -- but each time a tap comes in, tapCount increments.

the following:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"%d", [touch tapCount]);
}
```

continually increments tapCount as often as I tap it, and if I put this into that method:

```
if ([touch tapCount] > 1) { [gestureRecognizer setEnabled:NO]; }
```

it doesn't disable the gesture recognizer until after the tapCount has finished incrementing & then reset to zero.

Please help! I can't figure out how to stop tapCount from incrementing past 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"AnimateIn" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.7f];

//Add this
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(loadingViewDisappear:finished:context:)];
loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];



- (void)loadingViewDisappear:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *) finished context:(void *) context {
    NSLog( (finished ? @"YES!" : @"NO!" ) );
    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"AnimateIn"] && finished) {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right path -- I took another look at the [... animations:completion:] method and figured it out as described in my second post.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to use the [UIView beginAnimations:] method, so experimented again with the new way using blocks. I tried this before & don't know what I did differently this time, but the result was favorable.

I found that when I used this method to set the contentOffset of the scrollview, even though my tapCount is still incrementing as long as I keep tapping like a madman, the pages are now animating with the desired behavior, not erratically. As if it's not letting me "tack another animation on." Which is exactly the behavior I want.

```
-(void)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapRecognizer {

    CGPoint tapLocation = [tapRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    //a tap on the right side turns to the next page:
    if (tapLocation.x > self.view.frame.size.width/2) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
            [comicScrollView setContentOffset:nextPagePoint];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            NSLog(@"finished");
        }];
    }
}
```